# PHP XML Foreach shows 1 review

Tags: php, xml, loops, foreach

Iam trying to loop a XML file with Foreach but doesn't work. There are like 30 reviews in the XML File but only shows one. It shows the first person in the list but then on the bottom.

Iam trying to get better at PHP so dont know allot about it for now.

This is the code that i use.

```
<?php
$url = 'https://mobiliteit.klantenvertellen.nl/xml/autorijschool- 
wezemer%20' or die ('Niet verbonden');
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

foreach ($xml as $rijschool){
echo 'Voornaam: '.$rijschool->beoordeling->voornaam.'<br>';
echo 'Achternaam: '.$rijschool->beoordeling->achternaam.'<br>';
echo 'Woonplaats: '.$rijschool->beoordeling->woonplaats.'<br>';
echo 'Beschrijving: '.$rijschool->beoordeling->beschrijving.'<br>';
echo 'Aanbeveling: '.$rijschool->beoordeling->aanbeveling.'<br>';
echo 'Service: '.$rijschool->beoordeling->service.'<br>';
echo 'Deskundigheid: '.$rijschool->beoordeling->deskundigheid.'<br>';
echo 'Prijskwaliteit: '.$rijschool->beoordeling- 
>prijskwaliteit.'<br>';
echo 'Gemiddelde: '.$rijschool->beoordeling->gemiddelde.'<br>'.'<br>';
}
?>
```

Edit: here is the XML file Link https://mobiliteit.klantenvertellen.nl/xml/autorijschool-wezemer%20

And here is what iam getting [what current code shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GT5Xr.png)

Comment: show xml file..

Comment: Hi, please could you [edit] the question to include a small sample of the XML file which is enough to reproduce the problem, so we don't have to download it ourselves? You should aim for the code in questions like this to be a [mcve].

Comment: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
<?php
$url = 'https://mobiliteit.klantenvertellen.nl/xml/autorijschool-wezemer%20';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

foreach ($xml->beoordelingen->beoordeling as $rijschool){
    echo 'Voornaam: '.$rijschool->voornaam.'<br>';
    echo 'Achternaam: '.$rijschool->achternaam.'<br>';
    echo 'Woonplaats: '.$rijschool->woonplaats.'<br>';
    echo 'Beschrijving: '.$rijschool->beschrijving.'<br>';
    echo 'Aanbeveling: '.$rijschool->aanbeveling.'<br>';
    echo 'Service: '.$rijschool->service.'<br>';
    echo 'Deskundigheid: '.$rijschool->deskundigheid.'<br>';
    echo 'Prijskwaliteit: '.$rijschool->prijskwaliteit.'<br>';
    echo 'Gemiddelde: '.$rijschool->gemiddelde.'<br>'.'<br>';
}
?>
```

The problem you are having is that your `foreach` is iterating over the topmost node, but you want to iterate over a node lower down in the tree.

Comment: Thanks man! Thats exactly what I needed. I need to think like they are layers and choose a layer down every time.